# Altium: avoiding a collision check

Tags: altium, design-rules

I'm trying to create a rule to ignore a collision between some pads on the top layer and a track on another layer. So far my rule is this:

[image: rule]

But it still says I have a collision.

These are the pads that I want to ignore:

[image]

Comment: What is the specific error it shows?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be misusing keepouts; they apply across all layers.  So there's not really anything to do here by rule unfortunately, it's straight up overlapping.

Also, a note on something you've phrased: in general, you cannot set clearances between layers; the relations only apply to objects in the same layer, or special cases -- keepouts happen to be such a special case, so it does apply here, but mind it's not just any line that this works for.

Good(?) news is, in the several versions since this question was asked, keepouts have been changed to layer-specific objects, so you can have keepouts on top/bottom/multilayer/whatever, and they will apply to only the relevant layers.  This was added in... AD18? 20? I forget which, but it's there now, assuming of course you have a current subscription.

If you don't have current Altium, then I would suggest deleting that line, and replacing it with another solution; it could be shifted back and a larger clearance rule set on the relevant layers, or perhaps a polygon cutout can be placed there, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If those SM pads are unique then create a "pad class" that contains those SM pads then use that "pad class" for your new rule. I am not sure why you are using the keepout layer for this rule. The keepout layer/track is too global for a specific rule.

...something like this.[image]

Comment: I think OP is trying to make a rule so that this particular component **doesn't** violate when it overlaps a keep-out feature. You might want to do this, for example, if you have a connector that overhangs the board edge, and you're using Keepout layer tracks to define the board outline.

Comment: @ThePhoton, that is exactly what I'm trying to achieve.